# Browser compatibility issue of a java application

Tags: html, browser

How can we check browser compatibility issues from an application. For example if an application is only IE compatible and we need to make it work on Chrome and Mozilla what are the key steps taken for this? Do we have to change the html version or include any cdn etc?

Answer (score 0):

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9; IE=8; IE=7; IE=EDGE" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
```

**Add This Code In between head opening And headClosing**

Comment: Why should the OP "add this code..."? A **good answer** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.